# How to download (Assisted GPS) AGPS file on PC?

Tags: gps, gnss

I am trying to implement GPS receiver in software. Can I use AGPS file for faster locking of GPS satellites? I read somewhere that EPO files exist for Assisted GPS but I can't find any place to download this EPO data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [GPSrChive](http://www.gpsrchive.com/Shared/EPO/EPO.html) distributes a tool (see "Get EPO" at the bottom of the page) to download the files that Garmin receivers use.

**I've no idea if the format of the file will be obvious/documented or if the utility is trustworthy.  Use it at your own risk.**

Presumably the tool is (supposedly) doing something relatively simple to ask Garmin's servers for the same file a Garmin GPS would request on its own.